# Can I forcibly extract KML from a Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, kml

I know that in Google My Maps, I can click the folder icon and select Export to KML to download a KML file.

However, is it possible that, given the URL of someone's My Map, I can go in and get the KML out of it? I've read an answer that you can add the `output=kml` querystring to a URL, but that looks like something that used to work in old maps, but is no longer supported.

So, is there any way to currently do this with the current version of Google Maps?

Comment: [Link to mentioned answer](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/9138/35623) for reference.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible for the current version of My Maps now:

Under the Share icon, there is a Download KML option, like this:[image]

Comment: This is neat, and we use it currently, but what if I got the url to a map during runtime, and I need to extract the KML right then and there? Is there, I don't know, some kind of RESTful solution to get KML?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a Google account so start by signing in on Chrome.

1. Open the page with the embedded map in Chrome after Google log-in
2. RIGHT CLICK in page (not map) to View page source.
3. Search for the embedded map link (under google.com)
4. Left click hyperlink which opens in a new tab
5. In the Top Left corner, after the title of the map, is a grayed-out star. [Hover over to show: Star this map to view in Google Maps]
6. Left Click to highlight star.
7. In Top Right corner there is a Share icon and a View larger map icon [Hover over to show.]
8. Left Click "View larger map" icon
9. Map now opens in new tab IN YOUR GOOGLE MAPS.
10. LEFT Click the top 3 dot bar to export KML which you can open in Google Earth